# Custom sort with search api

Tags: 8, search

I have created a ViewsSort plugin that works on a normal view (like *taxonomy_term*) but not on a view based on **Search API** : it is not present when I click on "Add sort" in BO.
This sort is used to create a custom order of content types, and I use hook_views_data_alter() to provide it to views :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function mymodule_views_data_alter(array &$data) {

  // works on classic view
  $data['node_field_data']['inspiration_first'] = array(
    'title' => t('Custom search sort in page tags with inspiration first'),
    'group' => t('Search'),
    'help' => t('Sort content types in this order : dossier_inspiration, dossier_conseil, produit.'),
    'sort' => array(
      'field' => 'type',
      'id' => 'inspiration_first',
    ),
  );

  // doesn't work on search api view
  $data['search_api_db_default_search_content_index_content_type']['inspiration_first'] = array(
    'title' => t('Place inspiration first for custom search'),
    'group' => t('Search'),
    'help' => t('Sort content types in this order : dossier_inspiration, dossier_conseil, produit.'),
    'sort' => array(
      'field' => 'value',
      'id' => 'inspiration_first',
    ),
  );

}
```

Any idea ? Some sorts like Random work also on search api and I've provided the good table, I think (search_api_db_default_search_content_index_content_type).

Comment: By any chance could you post an example of your sort Plugin? I need this same functionality and am running into issues with how to get that to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

**Home  -> Administration  -> Configuration ->  Search and metadata  -> Search API**

& Edit your Index Search. Then your URL will be like below. In my case it's

**Content Search**

/admin/config/search/search-api/index/content_search/

So I'm using

`$data['search_api_index_content_search']['inspiration_first']`

I think in ur case it will be

`$data['search_api_index_search_content_index']['inspiration_first']`

Please share your URL if didn't worked.

Comment: Yes this works perfect! Took me a few hours to discover this answer, thank you! :)